# BigQuery / DataPrep - Is there a way to combine rows of the same KEY but different sequence numbers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I am using DataPrep to wrangle and import data into BigQuery.  My dataset contains "transactions" for each PERSON_ID with a new row for each SEQ_NO (transaction) as follows:

```
<code>
PERSON_ID   SEQ_NO  CODE   DATA1 DATA2 DATA3.... DATAN
1001        1       A      X     Y     Z ...
1001        2       B      X     Y     Z ...
1001        3       C      X     Y     Z ...
1002        1       A      X2    Y2    Z2...
1002        2       F      X2    Y2    Z2...
1003        1       A      X3    Y3    Z3...
1004        1       B      X4    Y4    Z4...
1005        1 ...
</code>
```

The first column PERSON_ID is the key which may have N SEQ_NO (starting with 1).  There is a unique CODE per SEQ_NO.  The rest of DATA is the same.

I've stumbled upon the "Convert Values to Columns" recipe which gets me close to option B below, but still has a unique row per SEQ_NO.

## DESIRED SOLUTION

### Option A: (Array)

```
<code>
PERSON_ID   new_SEQ_NO__CODE   DATA1 DATA2 DATA3.... DATAN
1001        [1:A,2:B,3:C]  X     Y     Z ...
1002        [1:A,2:F]      X2    Y2    Z2...
1003        [1:A]          X3    Y3    Z3...
1004        [1:B]          X4    Y4    Z4...
1005        [1:...
</code>
```

### Option B: (Values to Columns)

```
<code>
PERSON_ID   CODE_A  CODE_B  CODE_C  CODE_NN  DATA1 DATA2 DATA3....
1001        1       1       1       null   X     Y     Z ...
1002        1       null    null    ...      X2    Y2    Z2...
1003        1       null    null    ...      X3    Y3    Z3...
1004        null    1       null    ...      X4    Y4    Z4...
1005        ...
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an old post on Trifacta community that shows to ways to solve.  The syntax seems to have changed since this post, but essentially "Aggregate" becomes "Group":

https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L000058bYzWSAU/how-can-i-merge-mostly-duplicate-rows-into-one-with-a-multivalued-column-that-changes-per-row-in-the-source-data

Answer (score 0):

to obtain Option 1 you can use MERGE columns transform or MERGE Function from Search in Trifacta or select Merge icon from the toolbar. Do include the separator fields value as :

Next Pivot with row labels as PERSON_ID and DATA columns and aggregate values as LIST(merged column).

You may find this article helpful too https://community.trifacta.com/s/article/Use-case-Grouping-company-information-on-pivot